# Cannot install PureAdmin on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, linux, ubuntu

I try to build my own FTP server. I already installed pure-ftpd and created a user for the FTP connection. It works well, but now I would like to have virtual users, for which I need install PureAdmin on my Raspberry Pi. When I try it, I get the error:

> E: Unable to locate package pureadmin

I tried to install PureAdmin on my laptop (Kubuntu Linux) - it was possible. Can anybody help me and explain where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody help me and explain where the problem is?

The problem is that your Kubuntu laptop is an Intel CPU-based machine, while Raspberry Pi comes with an ARM processor. Binary packages compiled for one type of architecture cannot be run on the other.

When you use the `apt-get install` or the `apt install` command, you are effectively asking for a binary package, which program's author or maintainer prepared (compiled) for a specified architecture. Most Linux programs are compiled and packaged for Intel-based distributions only and PureAdmin seems to be one of them.

Your only chance is probably to compile the program from the source, which is described in detail in the [documentation](http://purify.sourceforge.net/?page=documentation&doc=install). You might run however into dependency problems, so it might not be a straightforward process.

You may go to the software's site and download the .deb version if available.